# Is there a general definition for "with good manners"?

Tags: employment, finland

Is there a general definition for "with good manners"?

Like it's used e.g. in relation to termination of employment relationship.

The Finnish employment law for example states that termination of employment relationship must be "with good manners" (it's translated as "factual"):

https://www-minilex-fi.translate.goog/a/ty%C3%B6suhteen-p%C3%A4%C3%A4tt%C3%A4minen-ja-luottamuspula?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fi&_x_tr_pto=wapp

> The employer is always required to provide a reason for dismissal, which in this context would be a lack of trust. This **basis must also be factual and weighty**. A similar reason for termination is not required from the employee, so the employee can terminate the employment relationship without reason.

However, if the expression was interpreted using:

> with good manners:
>
> The treatment of other people with courtesy and politeness, and
> **showing correct public behaviour**.

then the question arises.

---

In particular, maybe the confusion is from double meaning in Finnish where "asiallinen" may mean both "factual" or "good-mannered". And I actually read the latter, and thought that what it means is that it cannot be based on e.g. a racist or sexist remark, which may be seen as not good-mannered.

Comment: How is this related to the law? Maybe it's a question better for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Brandin The Finnish employment law, for example, says that arguments for termination must be with good manners.

Comment: I read it to mean that a bad argument could be e.g. "because we don't like his/her accent" or something.

Comment: Could you add the location and specify which law or code you are asking about.

Comment: "with good manners" sounds suspiciously like a questionable translation into English. I don't know any Finnish though; maybe the same words in that order (reverse-translated back into Finnish) imply something quite different in that language.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [asiallinen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asiallinen) means matter-of-fact, appropriate, businesslike.

Comment: @Brandin Again, why is "bad appearance" not businesslike? But I guess that would not count.

Comment: @mavavilj Are you talking about a dress code?

Answer (score 3):

The Finnish government's English version of [Työsopimuslaki](https://www.finlex.fi/fi/laki/ajantasa/2001/20010055) does not refer to "manners". It does refer to "particularly weighty reason" in Ch. 3 §5, and regarding termination in Ch. 7 §1 "The employer shall not terminate an indefinitely valid employment contract without proper and weighty reason". Subsequent §2 states what those reasons are *not* (illness, strike, politics, religion, filing a grievance). It is not prohibited to fire a person for being rude, if the factual circumstances are "weighty". The official Swedish version refers to "vägande sakskäl" in 7§1 and "sakliga och vägande" in 7§2, which I would unofficially translate as "weighty (factual) reason". The official Finnish version refers to "painavasta syystä" which Google tells me means "for a compelling reason".

Comment: Yes, well maybe the confusion is from double meaning in Finnish where "asiallinen" may mean both "factual" or "good-mannered". And I actually read the latter, and thought that what it means is that it cannot be based on e.g. a racist or sexist remark, which may be seen as not good-mannered.

Comment: Though the Finnish law doesn't refer to this, I guess it comes from the paraphrase "Tämän perusteen on oltava lisäksi asiallinen ja painava" in the commentary.